# Are p-value and Bayesian probabilities equivalent when applied to conversion rates?

Tags: probability, bayesian, statistical-significance, p-value, ab-test

For evaluating AB-tests, one can use the frequentist approach or a Bayesian one.

Using these websites I compared both with some example data:

- [Bayesian A/B-test Calculator](https://abtestguide.com/bayesian/)
- [AB Testguide](https://abtestguide.com/calc/)

Result:

```
+---------+---------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| Users A | Conversions A | Users B | Conversions B | p-value | Bayesian chance of A outperforming B |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 1000    | 100           | 1000    | 120           | 0.0764  | 7.7%                                 |
| 1000    | 100           | 1000    | 130           | 0.0176  | 1.8%                                 |
| 10000   | 1000          | 10000   | 1100          | 0.0105  | 1.1%                                 |
| 10000   | 1000          | 10000   | 1030          | 0.2412  | 24.1%                                |
| 17000   | 1700          | 10000   | 1030          | 0.2157  | 21.5%                                |
| 4000    | 2683          | 3000    | 2000          | 0.6402  | 64.1%                                |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

I'm aware of the different meanings of the probabilities given by the `p-value` and by the `Bayesian chance of A outperforming B`, thus it surprises me, that both seem to give the same values.

So are those two really equivalent?

And if so, why do all the simulation efforts involved in the Bayesian calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the last three cases don't give exactly equal answers when properly rounded (e.g. in the last one, the t-test gives 64.0% vs 64.1% in Bayes).

If you have two iid. normally distributed groups of equal size, then the p-value is going to be equal to the Bayesian result because they are *the same function*. The only difference lies in the interpretation.

The Bayesian calculator gives you extra knobs to answer additional questions in a business-user-friendly way. I'm not sure if the traffic/test duration variable is actually used to tune the precision, but if they do, this is another trick that approach buys you.

Finally, t-tests depend on a set of assumptions. There is some leeway, but at the very least you're shackled to a unimodal Gaussian. The online calculator doesn't support it, but the Bayesian approach is much, *much* more flexible, and you can use the underlying framework for all kinds of crazy distributions you may see in the real world, and to pool the results of several A/B tests in a principled way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the two independent and identically normally distributed groups don't even have to be of equal size. The differences, that is only visible in the bottom three rows in the question, sometimes also occurs with equally-sized groups. The Bayesian result simply fluctuates a bit. For example, I just re-ran `2683/4000` vs. `2000/3000` and the result for `Bayesian chance of A outperforming B` was `63.9%`.

Comment: Bayesian approaches account for precision; 1100 vs 1000 is stronger evidence for there being a 10% difference than 110 vs 100 or 22 vs 20, so the observation counts influence the probabilities (more observations -> sharper peaks).

Comment: Yes, but that is similarly true for the p-value.

Example: [group size 1000](https://i.imgur.com/2HQBDnI.png) vs. [group size 10000](https://i.imgur.com/nVnNGmz.png)